# noHistory equivalent in swift, no previous view controller

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have ListViewController and in it tableView. 
when I click on an item, the new view controller is displayed and the tableview from list view controller is also displayed in it and etc.
For example ListViewController -> ExpensesViewController -> VideoViewController.

I would like to go back to ListViewController when I press the back arrow no matter where I am. I just want the previous one to be removed from the stack after switching to the next view controller.

Comment: Hello, this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048095/no-history-for-a-screen-on-the-ios

Comment: Hello, thanks but where I have to type it? I use swift 4

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UINavigationController` have an array of `UIViewController`. 
So you juste have to remove the Controller in this array.

If I understand, you want to go back to ListViewController when you tap on the back button in the `VieoViewController`. 
So, after pushing `VideoViewController` you have to remove `ExpensesViewController` from the array of your navigation controller (for exemple in the `viewDidAppear` of `VideoViewController`)

```
var viewControllers = navigationController?.viewControllers
viewControllers?.remove(at: 0)
self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(viewControllers!, animated: false)
```